# How to get the Top N vales based on a column for each category in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am facing the issue while filtering out the data based on a "Date" column to fetch top 3 for each category. Below is the sample data:

[image]

Can anybody help me with this to get the below-expected output?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you trying to do this in Power Query, or using DAX? What does your required output look like?

Comment: @Olly- I was trying using the DAX.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (here dummy data); You can choice ASC or DESC based on your need:

[image]

```
Ranking by Date = var _cat = SELECTEDVALUE( Sheet1[Category])
return
IF(RANKX(FILTER(ALL(Sheet1), Sheet1[Category]= _cat), calculate(MAX(Sheet1[Date])),,ASC ,Skip)<=2, 1,BLANK())
```

or by Sale:

```
Ranking by Sales = 
IF (
    ISINSCOPE ('Sheet1'[Date] ),
    VAR ProductsToRank = 2
    VAR SalesAmount = [SumOf]
    RETURN
        IF (
            SalesAmount > 0,
            VAR VisibleProducts =
                CALCULATETABLE (
                    VALUES ( 'Sheet1' ),
                    ALLSELECTED ( 'Sheet1'[Date] )
                )
            VAR Ranking =
                RANKX (
                    VisibleProducts,
                    [SumOf],
                    SalesAmount
                )
            RETURN
                IF (
                    Ranking > 0 && Ranking <= ProductsToRank,
                    1
                )
        )
)
```

Or you can create a new table in DAX like this:

```
Top2 = GENERATE(VALUES(Sheet1[Category]), TOPN(2, FILTER(SELECTCOLUMNS(ALL(Sheet1[Category], Sheet1[Date]),"Cat",[Category],"Date",[Date]),[Cat] = [Category]),[Date]))
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting the below message using the above DAX:

"The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value."

Comment: Which one (measure or table expression)?  In my answer you can see dummy data on which I test it

Comment: Using DAX one:<br>
Top2 = GENERATE(VALUES(Sheet1[Category]), TOPN(2, FILTER(SELECTCOLUMNS(ALL(Sheet1[Category], Sheet1[Date]),"Cat",[Category],"Date",[Date]),[Cat] = [Category]),[Date]))

Comment: This one is a table expression; go to Data pane -> Table tools -> New table -> paste your statement